# Triggering a JQuery animate function & looping it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is (presumably) relatively simple, but let down by my (admittedly poor) understanding of jquery/Javascript.

The goal is simple - I want to 'animate' the opacity of a background image on a particular div (eventually I will apply this to others on the page, with the animation started/stopped according to the section being viewed - it's a horizontally scrolled page split into 'panels' the the viewer navigates with < & > buttons or named links).

Here's the script I've got so far (separate .js file, referenced in index.html);

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
"use strict";

function animateSec1BG() {
$('#section1').animate({
                opacity: 0,
            }, 1000, function () {
                $("#section1").css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/SlideBG-1.jpg)' }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
});


}
});
```

No errors are reported for that (Dreamweaver CC, code view).  At the bottom of index.html, after all scripts are loaded, I have this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#section1").animateSec1BG();
</script>
```

(the "#section1" bit I don't think is needed - code just didn't 'look' right without it - but doesn't work either way!).

Error returned states:

> TypeError: $(...).animateSec1BG is not a function

I'm totally lost and somewhat out of my depth here, so any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: `animateSec1BG` is a jquery plugin ?

Comment: You have to call simply `animateSec1BG()` in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with CSS animation;
(This animation change the back-color. If you want, replace the background-color element with background-image element)

```js
$.fn.animateSec1BG = function (state){
   
  if(state)
            $('#section1').addClass("sample");
  else
            $('#section1').removeClass("sample");

};



$(document).ready(function() {  $("#section1").animateSec1BG(true); });
```

```css
.sample {
        width:100px;
        height:20px;
        background:red;
        animation:myfirst 1s;
      -moz-animation:myfirst 1s infinite; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 1s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
      }


      @-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */
    {
    0%   {background:red;}
    50%  {background:yellow;}
    100%   {background:red;}
    }

        @-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
    {
    0%   {background:red;}
    50%  {background:yellow;}
    100%   {background:red;}
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1">
  Some info and etc.
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had originally tried CSS animation as my preferred option, but for whatever reason it wasn't working.  Your sample however, does.

Answer (score 2):

The function is defined within jQuery scope not global. Add the function to jQuery like:

```
jQuery.fn.animateSec1BG = function() {

    $('#section1').animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, 1000, function() {
        $("#section1").css({
            'background-image': 'url(images/SlideBG-1.jpg)'
        }).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);

    });

}
```

Since the selector is hard coded, you can just define the function global one, and execute it when ROM is ready.

```
function animateSec1BG() {
   // code
}
```

And call it `animateSec1BG()`. As for the loop, you can call the function within a interval using `setInterval()`

```
setInterval(animateSec1BG, 1000);
```